# Ignore null values in a text file in Python

Tags: python, csv, text

I am trying to remove/ignore the Null values from my text file, but it wasn't successful. Have referred to some online solutions but that dint resolves the issue. I am new to Python, any help will be greatly appreciated.
`##` is the demiliter to seperate records.

Following is the sample of the input file when viewed in VS code:

```
location| test 
abc|  4/13/2022 3:26:38 PM abc: 'flight' Changed From: North Canal Street NUL 4/13/2022 
test|value 
##
...
```

NUL got introduced in couple of lines which is causing error while

```
with open("dummy.txt",'a') as out:
    with open("output.txt") as file:
        for line in file:
            if not line.strip():
               if ('##' not in line):
                    out.write(line);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the `NUL`?

Comment: Are you simply trying to remove the `NUL` text, or ignore the line altogether if it includes `NUL` in it. The former is doable with a simple `replace()`

Comment: `line = line.replace('NUL', '')`?

Comment: This question would be improved if you provided both sample input and expected output.

Comment: Are the `<br>` tags actually in your data or was that an attempt at formatting on your part? If they are not really there, please [edit] your question to show us how the file really looks. You can switch off reflow by highlighting and pressing the `{ }` button. HTML tags don't do what you might expect.

Comment: `if not line.strip():` means `if line.strip() == "":`: Do you really want that - sounds more like you want `if line.strip():`?

Comment: When I am trying to copy the contents of the file to another file it is not totally copied due to NUL and its stops at the place it encounters NUL.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file in Notepad++ and copy to another file helped in removing NUL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).